# WPF TextBox_LostFocus event to binding object

Tags: wpf, listview, binding

So i have this `TextBox` template inside my `ListView`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="textboxCell">
              LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

And my `event`:

```
private void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   // Get cell value by using sender Object
    string str= ((TextBox)sender).Text;
}
```

So as you can see i am get my `TextBox` value but how can i get my `Binding object` ?

Comment: How do you get that `TextBox`? You have a `DataTemplate` but no `TextBox` defined? Why do you need the Binding object in UI?

Answer (score 0):

> So as you can see i am get my `TextBox` value but how can i get my `Binding` object ?

Cast the `DataContext` of the `TextBox` to your data object:

```
private void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = sender as TextBox;
    if (textBox != null)
    {
        YourClass dataContext = textBox.DataContext as YourClass;
    }
}
```

Or, if you want to get a reference to the actual binding, you could use the `BindingOperations.GetBinding` method:

```
var binding = BindingOperations.GetBinding(textBox, TextBox.TextProperty);
```